# how replace key from HashMap to values in newMap?

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, key, key-value

```
HashMap<String,String> map1 = new HashMap<String,String>(); 
map1.put("1","Russia"); 
map1.put("2","USA");
```

//values from map2 to key in map1 or in newMap

```
HashMap<String,String> map2 = new HashMap<String,String>(); 
map2.put("1","Moskow"); 
map2.put("2","New York");
```

//how relplace value to key? in new Map

```
HashMap<String,String> newMap = new HashMap<String,String>(); 
newMap.put("New York","USA"); //key "2" from map1 & map2
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you describe it, it looks like this

```java
Set<String> kyes = map1.keySet();

for(String key: keys){
 String newKey = map2.get(key);
 String newValue = map1.get(key);
 newMap.put(newKey,newValue); 

}
```

Comment: Instead of iterating over the `keySet()`, to perform a lookup into the same map, you can iterate over the `entrySet()` which provides key and value in the first place. Which works best with the `forEach` method, e.g. `map1.forEach( (key, value) -> newMap.put(map2.get(key), value) );`